# Django 1.10 - Plug new app into django

Tags: django, django-apps

I have a trouble with plugging recently created `app` called `pages` into a django project.

**My pages apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PagesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'pages'
```

**My settings.py, installed apps**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig' # pages.apps.pages fails too
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

> ImportError: No module named 'pages.apps.PagesConfigdjango';
>   'pages.apps' is not a package

Does anyonw knows what is wrong there? I did everything according the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial02/), but django still cannot to plug my app. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Is your file called app or apps?

Comment: apps.py ... sorry for typo in subtitle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a comma after your entry.

```
'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
```